# issues with jquery prepend

Tags: jquery, append, prepend

i'm at a loss for why this isn't working..

this works:

```
$(this).prepend("<div data-role='header'><h1>Hi</h1></div>");
```

however when i do this my entire page goes blank (nothing loads), but there's no error:

```
$(this).prepend("<div data-role='header'><a href='link'>Link</a><h1>Hi</h1></div>");
```

this also doesn't work:

```
$(this).prepend("<div data-role='header'><h1>Hi</h1></div>");
$(this).find('div[data-role=header]').prepend("<a href='link'>Link</a>");
```

nor does this:

```
var string = "<div data-role='header'><a href='link'>Link</a><h1>Hi</h1></div>";
$(this).prepend(string);
```

and here's the context in case that matters:

```
$('div[data-role*="page"]').each(function (i) {
    if ($(this).children('div[data-role*="header"]').length != 0) {
        alert("has header");
    } else {
        if (i == 0) {
            var string = "<div data-role='header'><a href='link'>Link</a><h1>Hi</h1></div>";
            $(this).prepend(string);

        } else {
            $(this).prepend("<div data-role='header'><h1>Hi</h1></div>");
        }
        $(this).find('div[data-role=header]').page();
    }
});
```

how do i get this to work?

Comment: I don't see anything that would cause that behavior. Does it still do it if you comment out the line with `.page()`?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific when you talk about *not working*? Javascript error? Unexpected behavior (in this case describe the expected behavior and how does it differ from what you are observing)? BSOD? Apples start falling from the sky? Something else?

Comment: Please be more specific: this: $(this).prepend("<div data-role='header'><a href='link'>Link</a><h1>Hi</h1></div>"); " works fine.

Comment: a litte fiddle on jsfiddle would be welcome

Comment: Here's a quick attempt at a fiddle that I'm working on: http://jsfiddle.net/mlms13/xxa6X/1/  I'm not quite sure what the `page()` function is supposed to do, so I commented it out.  With that line commented out, it seems to work fine for me.

Comment: thanks for the responses. it still doesn't work even if i comment out .page(). and by "not working", i mean that the body of the page doesn't load (see my other comment below), but there are no errors in the console. i think something else is going on besides the prepend bit. oh, and this is happening in firefox and chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using version 1.4 or greater, try dynamically creating the elements you need using the new element creation syntax introduced:

```
$('<a />', {
    'href': 'http://www.google.com',
    'target': '_blank',
    'text': 'This is a link',
    'class': 'myClassName',
    'css': {
        'top': '20px'
    }
           }).appendTo('<div />', { 'data-role': 'header' })
             .prependTo($(this));
```

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, if the script in which the prepend function is used in the -tag, it will not work because the script is loaded before the DOM is ready.

To avoid this kind frustration, is a good habit to place your javascript before the  tag.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are using jQuery mobile it appears it works as intended on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/9rTCS/1/).  What browser are you testing this on?

**Updated** jsfiddle to be a more complete example so the page transition works from the first page.

Comment: thanks for the help. yes, i'm using jquery mobile. this is quite strange! i guess there's something else in my page that is causing this to not work. the contents inside the body are being loaded using PHP (basically it writes in the contents from another file), and it appears that when i add that link part, it doesn't load anything past the <body> tag. i have no idea why these would be related. is there any method for debugging this?

Comment: shouldn't document.ready (in which i'm running that code) run AFTER the body is fully loaded? so it really makes no sense that the body isn't loading, regardless of what i change within document.ready.